# Computing variance, standard deviation in python

Tags: python, calculated-columns, deviation

> How to calculate data distribution (variance and standard deviation) on Python 3, if the data has > given with atribute Jumlah_individu?

[image]

this is my code to calculate mean (I have get it) but for varience and standard deviation i cann't

Comment: Please post your code, not an image of the code. Also we need to know what `data` is: a pandas dataframe? numpy ndarray? list-of-lists? Please show `data.info()`

Comment: Ok it's pandas since you reference the column by `data.jumlah_individu`

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module. Maybe that'll be helpful.

```
>>> import statistics as stats
>>> alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,2,2]
>>> stats.median(alist)
2
>>> stats.mode(alist)
2
>>> stats.mean(alist)
3
```